# Closing a steam game after its open on Windows

Tags: python, windows, steam, windows-11

I was able to open a steam game with Python, but I can't get this to close:

```
import time
import subprocess

steam = subprocess.Popen("start steam://run/4000", shell=True)
time.sleep(10)
steam.kill()
```

When steam.kill() executes nothing happens. The game continues to run.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The Popen creates a process to run the start command.  the start command makes use of windows url scheme handling to launch steam.   you wind up killing the process that had the start command (which probably already exited) vs killing the steam process.